# How to join 2 Excel connections?

Tags: excel, ms-access, join

I've got 2 connections in a worksheet, querying an`.accdb`. How can I get an inner join on them within Excel?

**Restrictions:**

- One of the existing connections returns a **crosstab** query. Crosstab queries cannot be used as subqueries in Access directly within an SQL string (the `TRANSFORM` keyword cannot be used after the `FROM` keyword). The crosstab must be saved as a new querydef first, and then the querydef is used as an alias
- Both connection strings have `WHERE` criteria that change dynamically and are generated on-the-fly, hence it's not practical to open up the `.accdb` and change a crosstab querydef constantly especially in a multiuser environment

Hence I stress I want the join to be done within Excel. Since all the required data gets pulled in and stored locally in the spreadsheet after a `Refresh All`, surely we have all we need to perform a join in Excel...